# Calculate processing time

Tags: c#

I am using C# / .NET 1.1; how can I calculate the processing time, for example for copying a file from 1 system to another?

Comment: just calc process time for copy file

Answer (score 14):

[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
CopyFile();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed : {0}", sw.Elapsed)
```

This class in not available in .NET 1.1, instead you can use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx) API

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

...

long start;
long end;
long freq;
QueryPerformanceCounter(out start);
CopyFile();
QueryPerformanceCounter(out end);
QueryPerformanceFrequency(out freq);
double seconds = (double)(end - start) / freq;
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed : {0} seconds", seconds)
```

Comment: am using .net 2003..so its not possibile there.

Comment: It's the kind of thing you should have specified in the question... we can't guess it ! See my updated answer for a .NET 1.1 solution

Comment: @Blindy : who's wrong ? me, maxy ? and about what ? Stopwatch is not supported in 1.1, but QueryPerformanceCounter is a Windows API supported since Win95/NT3.1...